# Want to add dynamically calendar entries in asp C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Here is the script which i used

```
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 3;
    function addInput(divName) {
        if (counter == limit) {
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
        }
        else {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = "Experiment Date" + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            counter++;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<body>
<form name="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Experiment Date 1 <br/> <input id="demo2" type="text" readonly="true" name="myInputs[]" runat="server"/>
     </div>
      <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server"  Text="Add more Experiments" onclientclick="addInput('dynamicInput')"/>

</form>
```

i also use date picker for the calendar entries, my question is that when i run the page the page is showing one entry but after click on the add more experiments the division is generated but somehow it is disappear in a second i think it is some problem of page load so what is be the solution of this and as my original form have multiple entries so can i use it there and is there is any good solution rather using this method.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" value="гггг-MM-дд" name="datepicker1"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#datepicker1.form-control').datepicker(
                            {
                                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
                    </script>
```

This is with bootstrap, inside code you can use

string datepicker = Request.Form["datepicker1"];

Sorry if I don't help you.

Comment: if code will inside <asp:UpdatePanel>, then use 
function pageLoad(sender, args){
$('#datepicker1.form-control').datepicker(
                            {
                                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
}

Answer (score 0):

your code is working I changed only:

```html
<input ID="Button1" type="button"  value="Dodaj" onclick="addInput('dynamicInput')"/>
```

And maybe in js when u add new input set id for it, to easily get data.

I hope i helped.